# Parent class constructor can't access child fields without Timeout

Tags: javascript, class

I am making an application using JavaScript. One thing that I noticed is that when I call super() from child class constructor, I cannot use child class fields.

For example:

```
class Parent {
    constructor() {
        console.log(this.x);
    }
}
class Child extends Parent {
    x = 5;
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
}
```

```
Output: undefined
```

As you see, the parent constructor cannot access the x field of the child constructor. There are similar questions on stackoverflow like:

[Access JavaScript class property in parent class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55479511/access-javascript-class-property-in-parent-class)

The solution they give is to use an init() method on the Parent class. I realized that every method other than the constructor of the Parent class has access to child fields.

```
class Parent {
    init() {
        console.log(this.x);
    }
}
class Child extends Parent {
    x = 5;
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.init();
    }
}
```

```
Output: 5
```

However, I can also get access to the x field by using Timeout with delay of 0:

```
class Parent {
    constructor() {
        setTimout(() => console.log(this.x), 0);
    }
}
class Child extends Parent {
    x = 5;
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
}
```

```
Output: 5
```

All the answers on stackoverflow give the solution, but nobody explains how and why this happens. So my question is:

> **1. Why the constructor doesn't have access to fields of the child class?**

> **2. Why adding a timeout function gives access to the fields of the child class?**

Comment: The field `x = 5;` acts as `this.x = 5;` inside the constructor _after_ the `super` call. `this` cannot be used in the constructor of a derived class before `super`. I think something related is mentioned in [How does the "this" keyword work?](/q/3127429/4642212).

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add ```extends Parent```.

Comment: So you mean that ```x = 5``` is executed as ```this.x = 5``` inside the constructor? And so until we don't call the ```super()``` method, this will not point to anything?

Comment: See [Why isn't this allowed before super()](/q/43539654/4642212). `this` only exists once execution reaches the base class through a series of `super` calls. Only after those `super` calls, class fields get applied; they can only be added as properties to `this`. A `this` has to exist first.